# VS Code keep focus

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I am editing a file in VS Code, then alt-tab (or click) another program to view something else, then go back to VS Code, the focus has shifted over to the side panel, which prevents me from immediately typing in the editing panel. I find it really annoying to have to change the focus back to the editing panel every time (by either clicking or using keyboard shortcuts). Is there a way to have VS Code keep the focus where it is until I change it, even if VS Code is in the background for a bit?

This does not happen when my workspace is a local folder, but it does happen when my workspace is a remote folder connected via SSH (using the "Remote - SSH" extension).

Comment: I don't experience this; mine defaults to the editor. I definitely haven't set up anything fancy, and am running the latest version (1.60.2). I would assume this is some sort of bug due to either your hardware or a plugin you are using. Have you tried this on a fresh machine and fresh installation of VS Code? What version of VS Code are you using?

Comment: Hmmm... I now see it doesn't happen when I'm in a local folder on VS Code. It DOES happen when my workspace is a remote folder connected via SSH.